# Answer Ordering (on your Profile Page) for 'Votes'

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

Hi,

When you order by votes on your **Profile Page**, for questions with the **same number of votes** what do you think of then ordering them by **accepted answer**?

So as an example, if I has answered 10 questions, each having three up votes and two of them having been accepted as the answer, on my profile page i would like to see the accepted answers appearing above the other question with the same amount of rep given to me.

Edit: So that I'm clear, this suggestion is for **your profile page** when viewing your answers.

Comment: And what about the two accepted, which one appears first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems innocuous enough (another sort column added to the existing query). I'll check into it.

Comment: Hi Jeff, just to clarify my question was based around the users profile page list of answers. I have edited my post as i didnt think i make it clear what i meant.

Comment: @kevc ah, yes, that makes more sense. thank you.